# Installing ghc binaries on Linux (can't find libgmp.so)

Tags: linux, haskell, installation, ghc

I am trying to install the Haskell Platform on Linux for the first time (I'm also a fairly new Linux user). The victim system is a fresh Red Hat system. And everything involved here should be 64 bit.

The directions at the platform website [1] indicate that I need a ghc7.0.3 to boostrap things. They provide a link to a generic binary of ghc-7.0.3 to do this. I fetched this and ran

```
$ ./configure ...
$ make install ...
```

as per the directions without incident (it is a binary, so no compilation needed)
However, when I tried to run ghci I get the output.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.0.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: gmp (libgmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

For some reason ghci cannot find libgmp.so. Running ghci ultimately invokes

```
  /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.3/ghc
```

with a mess of options. I checked the dependencies via ldd

```
$ ldd /usr/local/lib/ghc-7.0.3/ghc
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe5f5c000)
    libncursesw.so.5 => /lib64/libncursesw.so.5 (0x0000003ee7000000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x0000003ee5800000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x0000003ef3000000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x0000003ee5000000)
    libgmp.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3 (0x0000003ee4400000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003ee4c00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003ee5400000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003ee4800000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x0000003ef3400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003ee4000000)
```

and it shows that it foud libgmp. libgmp is in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/lib64.
I am not sure how to get further with this. Any suggestions?

[1] http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/linux.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You either add `/usr/local/lib` and/or `/usr/local/lib64` to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or add them to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, or (since you already have `/usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3`) add a missing symbolic link:

```
cd /usr/lib64
sudo ln -s libgmp.so.3 libgmp.so
```

(and perhaps the same for /usr/lib).

Note that /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3 might be a different version from /usr/local/lib64/libgmp.so, make sure ghc can actually be used with the former.

Comment: Many thanks. Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /usr/local/lib fixed this as well as adding the symlink in /usr/lib64 targeting libgmp.so.3. I guess I am still puzzled, I assumed since ldd found /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3, why'd it fail without the libgmp.so symlink?

Comment: I don't know if I'm right about this, but I just read somewhere that symlinking binaries or libraries is a very bad idea. Some guy said and I quote: "Never symlink binaries unless you've a gun pointed at you". Anyway, I just followed your answer and it worked. I'm just not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: Just a note for non-standard libgmp.so.3 -> newer with non-standard libgmp.  ghc's ld step doesn't know about LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so linking apps using ghc will break, even though ghc/ghci/etc. will run.

Comment: On ubuntu (and maybe debian) you can fix the library error by installing the `libgmp3c2` package. This avoids the symlink hack.

Comment: GHC now has separate builds based on CentOS and Debian. Your problem might be that you downloaded the wrong one. (The suggestions above will still likely work for you, though.)

Comment: @Bakuriu 's comment above works - for ubuntu 14 it worked for me with `libgmp3-dev` (my apt didn't know about `libgmp3c2`)

Comment: @asattar I love how Linux people say big, mysterious things like that and then don't explain them. (I consider myself a Linux person, so that is not an outsider's criticism.)

Comment: @sinelaw, Thanks ! That's works great for me as well on Ubuntu 14.

sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev

Answer (score 19):

Installing gmp-devel package helped in my case (opensuse)

Comment: "sudo apt install libgmp-dev" helped here. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Messing with LD_LIBRARY_PATH and managed libraries is not necessary nor recommended.
Simply run `sudo dnf install gmp-devel.x86_64` on fedora 64bits.

Comment: sudo apt install libgmp-dev" is the better solution..

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that setting a symbolic link from libgmp.so to libgmp.so.3 is the right way to go.  What happens when you get a version update and so libgmp.so.3 disappears.  Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH seems like a better solution.

There's also another solution for RedHat/CentOS and by extension probably Fedora: install the gmp-devel package.  This sets up the symbolic link above, but does so with in the distribution (so updates should update the symbolic link also).

Comment: Installing gmp-devel on Fedora works great. This creates a new symbolic link (libgmp.so) pointing to whatever version is currently installed and, as a result, ghci runs.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `libgmp-dev`. For example, on Ubuntu:

```bash
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y libgmp-dev
```