# GHC fails to install

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to install the 64 bit GHC 7.8.2 binaries downloaded from haskell.org (the debian build). I get the following error message on `make install`:

```
Warning: cannot determine version of
/home/kutta/home/software/ghc-7.8.2inst/lib/ghc-7.8.2/bin/ghc :
""
Warning: cannot determine version of
/home/kutta/home/software/ghc-7.8.2inst/lib/ghc-7.8.2/bin/ghc-pkg :
""
ghc-cabal: ghcInvocation: the programVersion must not be Nothing
make[1]: *** [install_packages] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Note that I set my install directory to a custom one, but I get the same error when I leave it on default. Any remedies?

Comment: Wrong/missing libraries? 
What does `ldd /home/kutta/home/software/ghc-7.8.2inst/lib/ghc-7.8.2/bin/ghc` say? see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360724/installing-ghc-binaries-on-linux-cant-find-libgmp-so?rq=1

Comment: It says "not a dynamic executable". Seems installation doesn't leave them in valid state.

Comment: What about `file /home/kutta/home/software/ghc-7.8.2inst/lib/ghc-7.8.2/bin/ghc` then?