# symlink from libgmp.so to libgmp.so.10

Tags: haskell, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I installed Haskell from here https://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html

following the steps listed there.
Then when I try to run ghci I got this message:

**GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... : can't load .so/.DLL for: libgmp.so (libgmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)**

I found this(link below) similar to my problem, but I couldn't get it working
[Installing ghc binaries on Linux (can't find libgmp.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360724/installing-ghc-binaries-on-linux-cant-find-libgmp-so)

How do I solve the links? and what are they? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `apt-get install libgmp-dev`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone didn't see @vivian's answer:

apt-get install libgmp-dev

I had the same problem, and it totally work for my ubuntu