# Error on initial execution of ghci (haskell)

Tags: haskell, ghci

I just installed GHCup from haskell.org. When I execute ghci I receive the following error:

> ```
> GHCi, version 9.2.5: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
> <no location info>: warning: [-Wmissed-extra-shared-lib]
>     libgmp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>     It's OK if you don't want to use symbols from it directly.
>     (the package DLL is loaded by the system linker
>      which manages dependencies by itself).
> ```

How should I address this issue?

There are similar problems on Google but nothing that is exactly the same.

Comment: Looks a lot like [Installing ghc binaries on Linux (can't find libgmp.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360724/installing-ghc-binaries-on-linux-cant-find-libgmp-so) to me.

Comment: Are you on linux? If so, it might help to check that `gmp` is installed in your system using the package manager of your distribution. I guess on ubuntu and related distros it would be something like `sudo apt install libgmp-dev`.

Comment: GMP stands for Gnu Multi-Precision. This is what supports arithmetics on arbitrarily large integer numbers, the `Integer` Haskell type. On Fedora Linux or similar, you would need to type: `sudo dnf install gmp gmp-devel`

Comment: Thanks all - installing libgmp-dev worked!  Your advice is much appreciated!